# Punctuating Adverbial Speech Descriptors

Tags: punctuation

This may have already been covered somewhere, though I can't find it, but I'd always thought that adverbs qualifying, describing, modifying the verb in speech delivery, required a comma before the adverb, as in, for example: "I did it," he said, ashamedly.

If this is not the case, so we have:'"I did it," he said ashamedly.', does it not make it sound like you are almost reporting what was said, as in: 'he said/used the word 'ashamedly', so it sounds like he quoted the word?

What's the grammatical difference, then, between saying, in direct speech, 'he said ashamedly' and saying'He definitely used the word 'ashamedly'?

Isn't there a pause in the speech descriptor but not in the other one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly common error called the "comma fault," which means a writer puts a comma where a period should go.  For example,

> The rabbit stopped dead in its tracks, it even stopped twitching its nose.

The comma fault here needs to be corrected with a period (or possibly a semi-colon), as in

> The rabbit stopped dead in its tracks.  It even stopped twitching its nose.

It could also be corrected by inserting the word *and* after the comma, in which case the comma wouldn't be "at fault":

> The rabbit stopped dead in its tracks, and it even stopped twitching its nose.

The only way your sentence "'I did it,' he said ashamedly"  could be incorrect is if it had a "period fault," as in

> "'I did it.' He said ashamedly."

in which case the word ashamedly would need to be put in quotation marks, as follows:

> "'I did it.' He said 'ashamedly.'"

I'm not suggesting the above sentences (viz., "I did it" and" and "He said 'ashamedly.'") make sense, but that's how they would convey the meaning that "he" said two things, both "I did it" and the word "ashamedly."

In conclusion, it all goes back to punctuation and a simple comma fault.  Your observation that "I did it," he said ashamedly" makes it sound as if the speaker said two things and not one is a straw man.  By that I mean any person who reads the sentence without the comma after the word *said*--provided s/he knows the correct way to read the sentence as it is punctuated--would understand the person to have said one thing, and that ashamedly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue, though, is specifically the punctuation, or non,for that matter, of adverbial speech descriptors, in terms of their qualifying/modifying, describing, the various verbs used to denote direct sppech, as in 'he said, she shouted, he bellowed, he asked, he thundered', etc. There is a pause before the adverb, however slight.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to both proof-read my comment and add a further point regarding 'There is a pause before the adverb, however slight,' because that obviously depends on whether an adverb follows the verb used, for example: "Did Brutus also stab Caeser?" Anthony asked increduously.

Comment: @cliffyboy:  In my way of reading "I did it," he said ashamedly, I do not put even a slight pause between "said" and "ashamedly."  I'm not suggesting everyone would do the same as I.  Moreover, one CAN insert a pause (and a comma) for a certain effect, kind of a dramatic pause, in which case a comma would be fine.